# Primefaces fileupload uploads only files < 30kb

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, servlet-3.0, mojarra

I'm having problems with my chat project, which i'm building for learning purposes. I'm having a weird little problem with PrimeFaces fileUpload component. It is working fine for a file not larger than 30kb (for larger file it throws HTTP error 400).I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3, Apache commons-io 2.3, Commons-fileupload 1.3. Because this is my learning  project, i have uploaded it on public git repository, which is, for better understanding of the problem, accessible here: https://bitbucket.org/salkovich123/testfileupload.git

The fileUpload component is located in file register.xhtml.

I am also sharing my web.xml file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This are the header details, which throws HTTP error 400 (bad request)

[image]

UPDATE #1

This is most definetly some kind of jQuery problem, because error is thrown in browser console, and no other server side methods are called after thrown error

Comment: @Kulkeltje I am toying with this code for 4 days now, and I noticed an interesting thing. If i remove Atmosphere dependencies and configuration in web.xml, fileuploading works fine. I also created  a separate project with shiro and fileupload, and the fileUpload component is working fine. I am really frustrated about this problem...

Comment: @Kukeltje, We didn't understand each other. I tried what you suggested.. FileUpload worked without Shiro. I also use Shiro in other projects with  fileUpload without any problems. i will remove Shiro and put another link to testing project in my post as you suggested.

Comment: @Kukeltje, you were right, I managed to recreate the error only with fileupload included in project. I edited post above with new informations.

Comment: @Kukeltje, In this test project, there are no occurences of Atmosphere API, as i created new fresh project, which only uses primefaces library dependencies and apache fileuploaddependencies. I am using servlet 3.0 and mojarra 2.2.7.  Its really frustrating, as i spent all night debugging, and i cant find the solution. I removed atmosphere tags from question...

Comment: So it works with servlet 2.6 and/or with myfaces? And as long as you don't post an [mcve] in here, I at least am not giving it a try…

Comment: @Kukeltje I gave the link to the repository, where minimal example is (bitbucket repository -GIT) - https://bitbucket.org/salkovich123/testfileupload.git   Here you can check the source code of the minimal example only with PrimeFaces 5.3, Apache Commons and Mojarra 2.2.7. I think I already found the solution.  I erased my IDE from the computer, along with Glassfish 4.1 application server. After reinstall everything works fine on same Mojarra version (2.2.7). I am testing it right now ... If everything will work fine, i will create an answer about reinstall.